# Rotating 3rd Person Character Programmatically from Unity's Standard Assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I am trying to automate a random rotation of a 3rd person character in Unity and I'd like the rotation to be **animated** as if I were turning the player myself using the out of the box controller and the WASD keys. The goal is an NPC that randomly rotates, looking for someone in a crowd.

Here is what I've attempted thus far, within a coroutine in update.

```
float xDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);
float yDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);
float zDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);

// Works but immediate
this.transform.Rotate(0f, yDegress, 0f);

// Works but immediate
this.transform.LookAt(new Vector3(xDegress, 0f, zDegress));

// Doesn't work 
rB.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, new Quaternion(0, yDegress, 0, 0), 0.5f);

// Doesn't work 
rB.MoveRotation(new Quaternion(0, yDegress, 0, 1).normalized);

// Works but immediate
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(xDegress, 0f, zDegress);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
    transform.rotation,
    Quaternion.LookRotation(newPosition, Vector3.up),
    0.5f);

yield return new WaitForSeconds(_pauseSeconds);
```

Here's the inspector for the NPC, which is Ethan from the standard assets.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Quaternion.LookRotation as the second parameter in the Quaternion.Lerp method?

Comment: Thanks. It has the same immediate effect as the other working lines. I've added my code.

Comment: what does `// Doesn't work ` mean exactly? Did you try do your stuff with `Time.deltaTime`? could you please add a complete code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all since it is a `RigidBody` you shouldn't use `transform.rotation =` nor any `transform.` method at all but stick to `rb.MoveRotation` or `rb.rotation`.

Than you used `Lerp` in a "wrong" way. What you want is a value that grows from `0` to `1`. Calling it only once with a factor of fixed `0.5f` allways results in a rotation halfway inbetween the first and the second 
one - immediately.

---

First you need a desired duration for the rotation.

```c#
// How long in seconds should the rotation take? 
// might be a constant or set via the inspector
public float rotationDuration = 1.0f;
```

Than before you start rotating get the start and end rotation

```c#
float xDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);
float yDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);
float zDegress = Random.Range(10f, 75f);

var currentRotation = transform.rotation;

var targetRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.Euler(xDegress, yDegress, zDegress);
// or
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(xDegress, 0f, zDegress);
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newPosition, Vector3.up);
// or whatever your target rotation shall be
```

Now since you already are in a Coroutine you can simply add a `while` loop performing the rotation within the desired duration (don't forget the `yield` though)

```c#
var passedTime = 1.0f;
while(passedTime < rotationDuration)
{
    // interpolate the rotation between the original and the targetRotation
    // factor is a value between 0 and 1
    rb.MoveRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, passedTime / rotationDuration);

    // add time passed since last frame
    passedtime += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
}

// to avoid overshooting set the target rotation fix when done
transform.rotation = targetRotation;

yield return new WaitForSeconds(_pauseSeconds);
```